# Is it possible to add test&set, test&clear to the bool class?

Tags: python-3.x

(This is not about an atomic test and set)

All I want is to be able to write code like this:

```
need_cleanup = True
...
if need_cleanup.test_and_clear():
    cleanup()
```

instead of:

```
if need_cleanup:
    cleanup()
    need_cleanup = False
```

IMHO this does not break anything in the bool class.

Attempts to add a method ended with:

> TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'bool'

It is probably related to the known limitation that the bool class cannot be subclassed, but I do not want to subclass it.

Is there a way around it?

---

**EDIT**: I think I've got the answer. It is not possible, because bool is **immutable**. Switching from `False` to `True` (or vice versa) replaces the bool object by a new one which is identical to the `True` or `False` constant respectively. Obviously, calling a method cannot do that. The forbidden subclassing was just drawing away my attention...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

> I thought about this last night, and realized that you shouldn't be allowed to subclass bool at all! A subclass would only be useful when it has instances, but the mere existance of an instance of a subclass of bool would break the invariant that True and False are the only instances of bool! (An instance of a subclass of C is also an instance of C.) I think it's important not to provide a backdoor to create additional bool instances, so I think bool should not be subclassable.
>   - [Guido van Rossum](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2002-March/020822.html)

In short, you can't add attributes to primitives, but you can subclass them (except when you can't).